# Wrong frame after adding transformed view to UIWindow or UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiwindow

The following code will break the frame (which will be enormous), as seen in iOS 8.1.3.

```
someView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001f, 0.001f);
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].subviews lastObject] addSubview:someView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    someView.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
}];
```

Removing the transformation and replacing it with a simple frame movement animation works well. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and reasoning I came to the conclusion that it might be a good idea to apply the transformation of someView *after* it has been added to a view. And this turned out to be the solution. So we write:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].subviews lastObject] addSubview:someView];
someView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001f, 0.001f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    someView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}];
```

Which works as expected.